# WPF ListView IsSelected Set Border Opacity

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview and padding must be 2 and color's getting system theme (using windows 8.1) but look very ugly.

```
<ListView.Resources>
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

**TIP:** I used CornerRadius = 10 in DataTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DT">
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Background="{Binding HEXRengi}" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="150" Height="100" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.RowSpan="2" CornerRadius="10"/>


        <ToggleButton x:Name="HEXRenkAl" Style="{DynamicResource DüzRenkPaletiDüğmeBiçimi}" Grid.Row="0" Click="HEXRenkAl_Click">
            <Border Background="{Binding HEXRengi}" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="10">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding HEXRengi}" Style="{DynamicResource SeçilebilirAmaYazılamazMetinKutusu}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </Border>
        </ToggleButton>

        <ToggleButton x:Name="RGBRengiAl" Style="{DynamicResource DüzRenkPaletiDüğmeBiçimi}" Grid.Row="1" Click="RGBRengiAl_Click">
            <Border Background="{Binding HEXRengi}" MinHeight="50" MinWidth="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CornerRadius="05">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding RGBRengi}" Style="{DynamicResource SeçilebilirAmaYazılamazMetinKutusu}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Century Gothic" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            </Border>
        </ToggleButton>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Look like this;

[image]

And IsSelected;

[image]

When i used setter property opacity value apply all item. **Just should apply on border, not all item**.

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemParameters.WindowGlassBrush}"/>
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Opacity" Value=".5"/>
</Trigger>
```

[image]

How can i do it? Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

> When i used setter property opacity value apply all item. Just should apply on border, not all item.

If you are wondering why opacity value is applying to all items, that is because you have named "Border" and you are targeting by name in your `Trigger`.

> ```
> <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
>     <ContentPresenter />
>  </Border>
> ```

Comment: I know but just want to know how to apply to the edges.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to understand your question. You should name the "_edge_" you are targeting and target this in your trigger. Also, if you try with Blend, it might be easier to play around.